# Change Legend Label in pheatmap

Tags: r, pheatmap

I'm using relatively simple code. I need to change legend title and legend size. Afterwards I would also like to add column annotations. The script is as follow.
Can't add image since I'm new to stack over flow.

```
pheatmap(L1S1Matrix, 
     cellwidth = 40, cellheight = 40, scale = "none",
     cluster_rows = T,
     cluster_cols = T,
     clustering_distance_rows = "euclidean",
     clustering_distance_cols = "euclidean", clustering_method = "ward.D",
     legend = T,
     legend_labels = NULL,
     fontsize = 12, fontsize_row = 12, fontsize_col = 12,
     treeheight_row = 100,
     treeheight_col = 100,
     angle_col = c("0"))
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.